# Trying to generate a Random String to Save to PG Table as client_number Rails 4, PGSQL

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate a "Client Number" automatically when an admin generates a new client in our Rails 4 app.

I have read several articles on this but most are talking about breakable tokens.

so far my Client model only has a client_number attribute and it is a string.

my model looks like:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save generate_client_number

  validates_uniqueness_of :client_number

  def generate_client_number
    self.client_number = SecureRandom.hex(2).upcase
  end

end
```

We are using PostgreSQL as our DB, I am relatively new to rails. after adding the above to our model, it errors out in the console this is the error it throws:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `generate_client_number' for #<Class:0x007fc59bdd7008>
Did you mean?  generated_attribute_methods
```

I am a little bit lost as to where I am going wrong here. any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I am sure this is an oversight on my part. Thanks in advance.

> **EDIT #1:**

The error has been eliminated by fixing the code error. And Adding

```
before_save :generate_client_number
```

however when I attempt to Create the random string and save to db I now get:

```
irb(main):013:0> Client.create
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Client Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."client_number" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Client id: nil, client_number: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of using a symbol correctly:

```
before_save :generate_client_number
```

These after_* and before_* hooks are defined by a symbol with the name of the method called, so you need to write **:generate_client_number**, with **:**, instead of just generate_client_number.

About the fact it is not generating a number, your error message implies your are getting a duplicate and having a roolback. I suggest you to try

```
self.client_number = SecureRandom.uuid.upcase
```

Comment: That eliminates the error issue however dosnt create or save the number into the record? Am i missing something here? -- Ill still Best answer as it dose eliminate the error

Answer (score 1):

Ill add my own answer here as well as I have resolved this issue,

It appears that the first time I attempted to create a Client it saved a record containing a nil ID, how or why I don't know.. however blowing out the client records and starting from scratch has resolved my issue. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you tried creating more than one record after blowing out the records, just in order to check if you don't get more rollbacks?

Comment: I have i just created 55 Clients successfully with no conflicts or rollbacks

Comment: Great! Congratulations.

Comment: And this is one of the goals of life, my friend. At least one new thing learned everyday.